# combine dataframe column with similar name. and concate values with separated by ',' (comma)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, string-operations

[input file contains the product and its price on a particular date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NftJ.png)

```
product  05-Oct-2020  07-Oct-2020 09-Nov-2020 13-Nov-2020
A        66.2         69.5        72.95       76.55
B        368.7        382.8       384.7       386.8
```

[output file should, combine all the days of month in one column and concatenate values with separated with comma (,)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDgbK.png)

```
product   Oct-2020         Nov-2020
A         66.2, 69.5       72.95, 76.55
B         368.7, 382.8     384.7, 386.8
```

i tried to change column name with date format , from '1-jan-2020' to 'jan-2020'
with

```
keys = [dt.strptime(key, "%d-%b-%Y").strftime("%B-%Y") for key in data.keys()]
```

and after df transpose we can use groupby.

like there is option to group by and sum the values as :-

```
df.groupby().sum()
```

is there something that can join values (string operation) with separate them with comma.

[click here to get sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i0xUlSIJPBnKu439_DKoB8_Qs9bJ0EyAz4AIv0zXRys/edit?usp=sharing)

any direction is appreciated.

Comment: please see the images of input file and desired output to understand

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to write a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html?highlight=grouper#pandas.Grouper) on the colums:

```py
inp = pd.read_excel("Stackoverflow sample.xlsx")

df = inp.set_index("Product")
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

out = (
    df
    .T
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq="MS"))
    .agg(lambda xs: ", ".join(map(str, filter(pd.notnull, xs))))
    .T
)
```

Using the provided sample this yields the following 5 first rows for `out`:
[image]

If you want to convert to a particular date formatting do

```py
out.columns = out.columns.strftime("%b-%Y")
```

which results in
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. but i don't have product column now.

Comment: sorry ! i had "index=False" in "to_excel()". i changed it to "True". and your code is working Properly. thanks.

Comment: The Product is became now the index of the dataframe. If you want to make it into a proper column, just execute .reset_index() on the dataframe.

Comment: If the answer solves your question, could you accept the answer?